# How do I use DynamicResource with TreeView so that I can have 2 TreeViews using the same key

Tags: c#, wpf

I've done this with list view in that I can define a resource:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <GridView x:Key="MyGrid" x:Shared="False">
        <!-- Defines what's in the grid view -->
    </GridView>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then I can have two views using the same Grid:

```
<ListView View="{DynamicResource MyGrid}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TodaysItems}"/>
<ListView View="{DynamicResource MyGrid}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TomorrowsItems}"/>
```

I'm trying to do the same thing with TreeViews. I've defined my tree view:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <TreeView x:Key="MyTreeView" x:Shared="False">
        <!-- Defines what's in the Tree view -->
    </TreeView>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

But I can't find what I need to do

```
<TreeView ???="{DynamicResource MyTreeView}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ClientData}"/>
<TreeView ???="{DynamicResource MyTreeView}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CustomerData}"/>
```

Can I even do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with `TreeView`. The reason why you can do it with the `ListView` is that it has a property `View` that can be set to different views. The view in this case is not a standalone UI element - it just, lets say, "settings" for the `ListView`. While the TreeView is a UI element just like `ListView`.

The command approach to re-use in XAML is Styles. You can define a style for you `TreeView` where you can define common properties and then apply it to as many elements as you like.

Here is an example how you can define a style:

```
<Style x:Key="MyTreeStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Red"/>
    <!-- Other property setters go here -->
</Style>
```

And here is how you apply it:

```
<TreeView Style="{StaticResource MyTreeStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ClientData}"/>
<TreeView Style="{StaticResource MyTreeStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CustomerData}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Pavlo Glazkov. My TreeView contains a ListView that has a Grid. I can DynamicResource the grid `<GridView x:Key="GridViewTemplate" x:Shared="False">` then use that from the two TreeViews I need. It reduces the amount of duplicated code but not as much as I had hoped.